# Javascript - input fields added dynamically not available

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am using Javascript to add new rows to a table when an image is clicked in a classic ASP page. Those rows contain a number of input fields with id's and names that include the row number. I am adjusting those ids and names for the new row. The operation is visibly working and the new row appears at the bottom of the table where I wanted to put it. Also, if I select the new row then view selected source in Firefox, I can see the new row's HTML with id's & names as expected.

When I submit the form, however, the new fields are not availabe and the loop below does not report them:

```
dim sItem
For Each sItem In Request.Form
  Response.Write(sItem)
  Response.Write(" - [" & Request.Form(sItem) & "]<br>")
Next
```

I am no Javascript whizz and have no idea why this might not be working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure (using the DOM inspector tool in your browser) that the added `<input>` elements really do have "name" attributes. Also, you can use your browser debugging tools to check the contents of the HTTP request sent to the server. If the form elements are reflected in the HTTP request, then the problem is on your server.

Comment: If you're using Javascript to post a form then server side code would not execute. Use Javascript to change anything related to UI. I belive code you posted above it some server side VB script.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked and the <input> elements do have names. How do I check the contents of the HTTP request in the browser please? (IE or FF)

Comment: Are the input elements being added into the `<form>` that is submitted, or just into the `<body>`? If they're not in the form, they could be left out of the submission.

Comment: Ted is right if your `<input>` fields are not wrapped inside a `<form>` they will never be submitted.

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed connected with the <form> tag. It was contained within a table which was closed before the </form> so the form was being closed prematurely. When I moved the form tag outside the table it started to behave itself.

Answer (score 0):

*I know you've worked it out now, but just thought I'd write up my comment for future visitors (and hopefully some points too?!)*

To ensure all the input fields you want are submitted with the form, they must be enclosed inside the `<form>` tags. e.g.

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="fooPage.asp" method="post">

    <!-- These two input fields will be submitted to fooPage.asp -->
    <input type="hidden" name="myhiddenField1" value="123" />
    <input type="text" name="myTextField1" value="hello world" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit myForm" />
</form>

<!-- These two input fields won't be submitted to fooPage.asp -->    
<input type="hidden" name="myhiddenField2" value="456" />
<input type="text" name="myTextField2" value="hello world 2" />

</body>
</html>
```